# Android change target sdk

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-manifest

I developed an Android application and I did the coding 4 months back and at that time I didn't have a Google Play account. Now I enrolled in Google Play and I would like to publish my app in the Play store. When I checked I saw the target SDK is 17 and I think now it is 19.

Do I need to change it to 19 for proper working on latest phones? Where do I need to change it?

I saw in the Android Manifest file there is one place:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

If I am changing this line to 19, will it solve the issue? If anyone knows, please help.

Comment: You didn't tell us what is the real problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to move to new version of API, your app works fine in newer versions of android, but if your want to use new SDK, you must be aware of changes that can act in your application
something like changes happen in `AlarmManager`

> **Note**: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time, but may be deferred and delivered some time later. The OS will use this policy in order to "batch" alarms together across the entire system, minimizing the number of times the device needs to "wake up" and minimizing battery use. In general, alarms scheduled in the near future will not be deferred as long as alarms scheduled far in the future.
>
> With the new batching policy, delivery ordering guarantees are not as strong as they were previously. If the application sets multiple alarms, it is possible that these alarms' actual delivery ordering may not match the order of their requested delivery times. If your application has strong ordering requirements there are other APIs that you can use to get the necessary behavior; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).
>
> Applications whose targetSdkVersion is before API 19 will continue to get the previous alarm behavior: all of their scheduled alarms will be treated as exact.
>
> [REFERENCE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score 1):

If u are using Eclipse then Right Click on you project -> Open Poroperties tab => Select Andorid =>and choose any required version as seen in image . [image: attached image]